# Getting an error saying TypeError undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

I am trying to display the data in Listview. First, I am filtering the data (JSON file) based on the selection that user made on the previous screen. I am passing the parameter to the next screen by saying :

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item)
```

Based on the above parameter, I did ListView.DataSource inside the render function. The only reason, I tried to do ListView.DatSource inside the  render function because to my understanding this is the only place where I can read the value of the parameter. When I tried to display my listView, I am getting an error saying:

TypeError undefined is not an object. Below is the screen shot:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView, ActivityIndicator, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import ServiceDetails from '../reducers/ServiceDetails';


class ServiceListDetails extends Component
{




  static navigationOptions =
  {
     title: 'SecondActivity',
  };




ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: .5,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
      }}
    />
  );
}


render()
  {


      var x =   this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item ;
      var newList = ServiceDetails.filter(obj => obj.fk === this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item)

      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.setState({
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(newList)

      }
    );


    return(
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
             <ListView

                dataSource={this.dataSource}
                renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}
                renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
/>

      </View>
    );

  }
}
```

Below is my JSON file:

```
[

    {
       "id":"1",
       "fk": "1",
       "addr": "TestAddress1",
       "phone": "(888)889-9999",
       "LatL":"33.234567",
       "Long2":"117.284725",
       "Online": "x"
    },

    {
        "id":"2",
        "fk": "1",
        "addr": "TestAddress1",
        "phone": "(999)-999-9999",
        "LatL":"33.971110",
        "Long2":"117.31111",
        "Online": ""
     },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're a mistake in define your JSON file. IN the last object in the array `","` not required it is not a valid JSON format so.

```
[

    {
        "id": "1",
        "fk": "1",
        "addr": "TestAddress1",
        "phone": "(888)889-9999",
        "LatL": "33.234567",
        "Long2": "117.284725",
        "Online": "x"
    },{
        "id": "2",
        "fk": "1",
        "addr": "TestAddress1",
        "phone": "(999)-999-9999",
        "LatL": "33.971110",
        "Long2": "117.31111",
        "Online": "y"
    }
]
```

Comment: JSON is not a issue. I already corrected the JSON file. I am still getting the same error.